# Importing a file inside Zip with OpenRead

Tags: import

How do I import a text file that is compressed inside a .Zip file using [`OpenRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html)?
I know how to do it using [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html)

```
pathArqANL = "file_xyz.zip";
Import[pathArqANL, {FileBaseName[pathArqANL] <> ".anl", "Table"}]
```

I tried something like this:

```
OpenRead[pathArqANL, Method -> {"File"}]
```

But I found no documentation about `Method`.

Comment: Why do you need to use `OpenRead` instead of `Import`? I'm not sure your way will work in all OS.

Comment: My file is about 1 GB or more. With "Import" it takes a long time, furthermore I have to filter some text inside file to get only numbers. By the way, compression rate 1 1/5, that is, files of 1 GB are stored as Zip with 200 MB.

Comment: Small hack `OpenRead[File["!unzip -p file_xyz.zip"]]`

Comment: @swish That does not work on Windows.

Comment: @LeoRon7 is there a single compressed file in each zip file? Would it be a problem to unzip the file before reading it? What system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 64 and there is only one file per Zip file. I think the drawback of this approach is the need to delete the uncompressed file after reading it... or not? If Mathematica crashes it will leave some garbage....

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stream the data, you could try something like

`strm = StringToStream[Import[pathArqANL, {FileBaseName[pathArqANL] <> ".anl", "String"}]]`

so that you can use ReadList etc which might be faster than Table Import if you already know the structure of the types of data in the file