# ReadList text file from GZIP

Tags: import

I'm trying to open several large .txt files which are located in a GZIP file. I am able to import each separate file using Import, but this is too slow. I do it like this:

```
dataFileNames = Import["file.gz","FileNames"];
dataImport[i_] := 
  Import["file.gz",{dataFileNames[[i]],"Table"]},"FieldSeparators"->";"]
```

Is there a way to apply the ReadList (or BinaryReadList) to make importing the files go faster? I prefer to not have to extract the files as this would take up a lot of space.

Comment: Do you have a zip or a gzip? They're not the same thing. gzip only compresses a *single* file, it makes no sense to get the `"FileNames"`, and it doesn't even work when I try it.  Thus before answering I need to make sure that you have gzip files. Normally, the original extension is also kept when gzip'ping, e.g. `file.csv.gz`. `Import` will transparently decompress and treat such a file as a CSV.

Comment: BTW `ReadList` *can* be made to transparently decompress a gzip. You need to `OpenRead` the file with the appropriate input stream `Method` (see `$InputStreamMethods`), then read from the stream, then `Close` it.  But I don't want to write an answer until you clarify the question. The code you cite doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear and OP is unresponsive to clarification requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar answer on [Importing a file inside Zip with OpenRead](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179023/importing-a-file-inside-zip-with-openread)

First off, gzip is not an archive format, it is a compression format, so "FileNames" will only ever return the one file.

Try:

```
strm = StringToStream[Import["file.gz", "String"]]
```

Then you can use ReadList etc. Like @Szabolcs mentions, Import will transparently decompress.