# OpenRead with Method->"GZIP"

Tags: import, streams, compression

## Aim

I'm trying to *"Low level"* read data from a **large** [`"GZIP"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GZIP.html) file as an [`InputStream`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputStream.html).

## Previous answeers

I found the discussion here [ReadList text file from GZIP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181993/readlist-text-file-from-gzip), where I found the [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) Option (hard to find in Mathematica documentation!)

The solution provided there seems unsatisfactory, as it implied uncompressing the whole file into memory as a `String`, prior to create the [`InputStream`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputStream.html). That defeats the propose of taking advantage of low-level access and deal with huge files that may not fit in memory using tools like [`SetStreamPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html) and [`Find`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Find.html).

```
StringToStream[Import["file.gz", "String"]]
```

## Motivation

The motivation is that uncompressing a *huge file* every time one needs to read it is inconvenient and should not be necessary when one only needs to access part of it's contents.

## Expectation

I expect to have an [`InputStream`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputStream.html) of the contents of one of the files inside a `"GZIP"` file.

From the documentation

> [`$InputStreamMethods`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$InputStreamMethods.html) gives the list of possible settings for Method in
> [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) and [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html).

```
MemberQ[$InputStreamMethods , "GZIP"]
```

Gives `True`.

## My tests

I have done the following: I started from a working code for uncompressed files, and just compressed the file and added `Method->"GZIP"` to the [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html),

```
OpenRead["MyCompressedFile.GZIP",Method -> "GZIP"]
```

Result

```
"OpenRead::noopen: Cannot open MyCompressedFile.GZIP.
```

## Minimum working example

```
Block[
    {
        stream,
        f = File["X:\\TestLargeFile.csv"], 
        fz, n = 0
    },
    stream = OpenWrite[f];
    Do[
        WriteString[
            stream,
            Sequence@@Riffle[ {n+=1,InputForm@AbsoluteTime[],RandomReal[1], RandomInteger[10^6]},",\t"]
            , "\n"
        ];
        ,{10^3}
    ];
    Close[stream];
    Echo@FileSize[f];
    fz = CreateArchive[
        f
        ,"X:\\TestCompressedFile.GZIP"
        , CompressionLevel -> 1
        , OverwriteTarget -> True
    ];
    Echo@FileSize[fz];
]


rstr = OpenRead["X:\\TestCompressedFile.GZIP", Method-> "GZIP"]
```

> OpenRead::noopen: Cannot open X:\TestCompressedFile.GZIP.

But the same file can be read without problems if no `Method` is defined

```
rstr = OpenRead["X:\\TestCompressedFile.GZIP"];
Echo[ReadLine[rstr], "",ToString];
Close[rstr];
```

[image]

## Main question

So, `"GZIP"` *should* be a valid [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) for  [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html), but it doesn't work as advertised.

**Is this a problem in the documentation, in *Mathematica* or in my implementation?**

**How can one have an `InputStream` of a `"GZIP"` compressed file ?**

Comment: Please post the file you're trying to read.

Comment: `$InputStreamMethods` does list `"GZIP"`, and [`DefineInputStreamMethod`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/DefineInputStreamMethod.html) has an example of *input stream method that opens a stream to a file inside a zip archive*. The documentation is not very generous about this, and the lack of details in the question makes it hard to give an specific answer. What's inside the "GZIP"?  This is hints a very interesting question, but in needs more work before it can be answered meaningfully/ The OP should [edit] the question to improve it [ask].

Comment: A GZIP is not an archive--it is just a compressed file. And yes, I need to OpenRead the file. It is rather Unix and Mac specific. 
I am sorry that @rhermans thinks this is insufficiently clear, but what I was trying to say is
"If I compress a file by gzipping it, I can no longer use the OpenRead command that works fine on the original file, even when I add the Method->"GZip" option"  
Indeed I have looked at all the small hints and examples in the MMA documentation, but haven't found an example that uses the "GZIP" option;a google search doesn't help either.

Comment: And @roman, no I will not post the file because it is over 100MBytes--why I want to gzip it. Suffice it to say it is a text file (even though the extension is .dmp, yes, which should not cuase an issue with OpenRead).

Comment: OK, I'm trying to save this question from closure. I provided a minimum working example to create a GZIP file from random data. Motivation to want this and a plausible reason not to want the solutions already posted. I also linked the documentation that suggest this should work. I hope this makes the question answerable is a way that may help the OP.

Comment: On Linux (which is OS, which supports pipes) the following trick works: openStr = OpenRead["!(/usr/bin/gzip -d /home/acus/test.txt.gz -c)"] . Test that it indeed works: Echo[ReadLine[openStr], "", ToString], which outputs the first line of the content I wrote into my file test.txt, which was then manually  gzipped. Unfortunately InputStream with Method->GZIP, don't work for me also. The above construction I think is equivalent to what your want to achieve, since it manually constructs pipe using systems gzip to standard output (option -c).

Comment: @Acus very nice! AtM don't have a Linux environment to play with that. Does *pipes* prevent the huge file to be dumped into memory?

Comment: @rhermans Not sure. Pipes provide the mechanism to pass output from one command to the other. If the second command is not ready to "accept" the input which comes from the first one, I think the whole process is suspended (so, no memory is used?). That is just my opinion.

Comment: It appears `stream = StringToStream[Import["X:\\TestCompressedFile.GZIP", "String"]]` does not load all the data into memory after all.  Can somebody else confirm that is the case? I tested with the MWE above modified to `10^6` lines.